# How fast a quantum state updates in a quantum experiment when the experimental setup itself changes. Are there known experiments on this?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-optics, interferometry

Consider the following Sagnac interferometer setup:

[image]

where $B$ is a beam splitter which can be raised and lowered with an adjustable frequency $f$, $D$ is a detector which does not click when $B$ is up and clicks when $B$ is down. $S$ is an electron beam source which fires single electrons with some classical velocity $v << c$

I am trying to model the hypothesis on whether there is a finite speed that the quantum state updates as the experiment setup changes due to raising and lowering $B$. If there is a finite speed $u$, then a delay between the appearing and disappearing of the clicks registered and the raising/lowering of $B$ should be observed

Let $\lvert ⟳\rangle$ and $\lvert ⟲\rangle$ be the clockwise and anticlockwise route of the electron travelled respectively. When $B$ is down, we have $\lvert ⟲\rangle$ arriving the detector which produces a click. When $B$ is up, we have instead $\lvert ⟲\rangle + \lvert ⟳\rangle$ arriving at $D$ which does not produce a click. Thus when $B$ is send to oscillate at a frequency $f$, we have the following state in the system:

$$\frac{1}{f}(\lvert ⟲\rangle + \lvert ⟳\rangle) + \lvert ⟲\rangle$$

which after normalisation, we have:

$$\sqrt{\frac{f+1}{f+2}}\lvert ⟲\rangle + \sqrt{\frac{1}{f+2}}\lvert ⟳\rangle$$

Thus as $f \to \infty$, contributions from $\lvert ⟳\rangle$ vanishes and $D$ will be always clicking. Likewise when $f \to 0$, we have equal contributions from $\lvert ⟳\rangle$ and $\lvert ⟲\rangle$ thus $D$ will not click. For all intermediate values of $f$, we end up with a scenario where $D$ clicks $\frac{f+1}{f+2}$ of the time and does not click $\frac{1}{f+2}$ of the time.

> 1. How does the deterministic oscillation of $B$ lead to a probabilistic outcome on whether $D$ will click, is it due to the Heisenberg uncertainty principle that relates the status of $D$ clicking with the oscillation frequency?
> 2. How can I incorporate $v$ into my state description?
> 3. Are there known literature examples that investigate this phenomenon?

Comment: Where does your expression for state come from? If it's from the idea that "f+1/f+2 of the time its up and the rest its down" then you need a density matrix, not a pure state. If its not, then I simply don't undertstand where its from.

Comment: As the recent edit showed, your guess is correct. I did not aware I need a mixed state to describe such scenario because of my wrong assumption that the pure state will somehow changes when the beam splitter is raised/lowered and that the oscillation is deterministic thus I don't see how it will become statistical. Editing to incorporate the density matrix consideration however will change the nature of the question completely result in the accepted answer to become unrelated, thus I have to leave it like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your treatment of the state of the electrons is incorrect and does not make sense. It is not clear what your expression for the "state of the system" is supposed to be, but it is not the expression for the state of any object involved in this experiment.

I will use $\lvert r\rangle$ for an electron that was not deflected by the beam splitter and $\lvert l\rangle$ for an electron that was deflected, corresponding to your "clockwise" and "counterclockwise" motions, respectively.

There are three options for an electron emitted from the source:

1. The electron passes through the beam splitter, its state is then $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\lvert l\rangle+ \lvert r\rangle)$.
2. The electron does not pass through the beam splitter, its state is them $\lvert r\rangle$.
3. The electron passes through the location of the beam splitter while it is being raised/lowered. It is unclear what its state after that is, since we don't really have an obvious model of what's happening in that case. This case only occurs if $f$ is so large that $v$ does not suffice for the electronic wave packet to pass the location of the beam splitter without it moving significantly. If you wish to analyze what one would expect in such an experiment, you need an entirely different approach.

"The electron" here stands equivalently for the decently localized wave packet wavefunction that a typical electron source will emit. Each individual electron is in one of these three states (although the third state hides a plethora of complicated possible states), and this state can deterministically be determined from the time of emission and its velocity, there's no randomness to it.

There is no such thing as a "state of the system", just the states of the individual electrons emitted, and you seem to expect electrons that have long passed through the beam splitter to somehow react to the splitter being lowered. This is not the case.